# How can we fetch multiple data stored in <div> table in karate?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I am trying to fetch set of data from a web table, stored/made using the `<div>` tags, not like the traditional html data tables. For example:

```
    <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="program_name" title="" style="width: 135px; text-align: left; height: 30px;">
        <span style="color: #00def; font-weight: 500;">Consumer xyz</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="business_val" title="" style="width: 119px; text-align: center; height: 00px;">
        11898
        <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
        <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
    </div>
```

So, I am using scriptAll() method for this and need data just for 'Consumer xyz' here but unable to do so.

```
    * def list = scriptAll('div div', '_.textContent', function(x){ return x.contains('Consumer xyz') })
    * delay(3000)
    * print list
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done @PeterThomas, can I expect a response on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give you one hint. This is how you can get a reference to the parent `div` of the row:

```
* def temp = locate('{}Consumer Banking').parent.parent
```

Now it is up to you:

```
* def businessValue = temp.locate("[tabulator-field='business_value']")
* match businessValue.text.trim() == '11898'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working as expected. Just one more thing, can we perform this inside function for multiple value checks, as we have it here for table headers else than business_value?

Comment: @UncleSam yes, please read the docs and understand how to combine and re-use JS functions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#function-composition