# how to get the input text value which is inside the table column in Dialog in Karate

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I got a table like below that renders in the dialog box. I am trying to capture the value of input which is inside the column.

The Xpath is /html/body/div[9]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input'
I did try multiple ways to get required value but could't get it so someone help me how to capture input value which is inside the particular , full xpath and css path is not working.

```
<table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>Room type:</td>
             <td><b>
                Deluxe Balcony Riverview - All Inclusive
                </b>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Date:</td>
             <td><b>
                01 Mar 2022
                </b>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Minimum Stay:</td>
             <td>            
                <input name="txtMinimumStay" type="text" value="1" id="txtMinimumStay" class="helper" title="The minimum nights a guest must stay in this room type" style="width:40px;">
                night(s)
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Maximum Stay:</td>
             <td>            
                <input name="txtMaximumStay" type="text" value="0" id="txtMaximumStay" class="helper" title="The maximum nights a guest can stay in this room type" style="width:40px;">night(s)
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Sold:
             </td>
             <td><b>
                0
                room(s)</b>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Allocation:</td>
             <td>
                <table>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td width="70px">
                            <input name="textAllocation" value="0" id="textAllocation" type="text" style="width: 50px">
                         </td>
                         <td style="font-size: 9px">Extra adult rate (per night):</td>
                         <td>
                            <input name="txtAdultPrice" type="text" value="21" maxlength="4" id="txtAdultPrice" class="helper" title="Extra person charge for adults" onchange="updateGuestCapacity(false)" style="width:40px;">
                            $AUD
                            <br>
                            <span id="Regularexpressionvalidator1" style="display:none;">Please only enter a whole number for the adult rate</span>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Rate:</td>
             <td>
                <br>
                <table>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td width="70px">
                            <input name="txtQuickRate" type="text" id="txtQuickRate" style="width: 50px;" value="85">
                            $AUD
                         </td>
                         <td style="font-size: 9px">Extra child 1 rate (per night):</td>
                         <td>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <input name="txtChildPrice" type="text" value="15" maxlength="4" id="txtChildPrice" class="helper" title="Extra person charge for children 1" onchange="updateGuestCapacity(false)" style="width:40px;">
                            $AUD
                            <br>
                            <span id="Regularexpressionvalidator2" style="display:none;">Please only enter a whole number for the child 1 rate</span>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td></td>
                         <td style="font-size: 9px">Extra child 2 rate (per night):</td>
                         <td>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <input name="txtChild2Price" type="text" value="7" maxlength="4" id="txtChild2Price" class="helper" title="Extra person charge for children 2" onchange="updateGuestCapacity(false)" style="width:40px;">
                            $AUD
                            <br>
                            <span id="Regularexpressionvalidator3" style="display:none;">Please only enter a whole number for the child 2 rate</span>
                         </td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>Availability Status:
             </td>
             <td>
                <table id="rblStopSellDialog" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:8pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td><input id="rblStopSellDialog_0" type="radio" name="rblStopSellDialog" value="0" checked="checked"><label for="rblStopSellDialog_0">Available</label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td><input id="rblStopSellDialog_1" type="radio" name="rblStopSellDialog" value="1"><label for="rblStopSellDialog_1">Stop sell</label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td><input id="rblStopSellDialog_2" type="radio" name="rblStopSellDialog" value="2"><label for="rblStopSellDialog_2">Closed to arrival</label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td><input id="rblStopSellDialog_3" type="radio" name="rblStopSellDialog" value="3"><label for="rblStopSellDialog_3">Closed to departure</label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td><input id="rblStopSellDialog_4" type="radio" name="rblStopSellDialog" value="4"><label for="rblStopSellDialog_4">On Request</label></td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't have time to go through such a complex dump - so I'll just point you to this answer. hope someone else can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65844733/143475