# How to grab and store div values in complex div in Karate

Tags: karate

I'm trying to store the value of last div

I have tired

- def val1 = scriptAll(.col-xs-4 , '_.innerHTML')---output is showing ""
- def val = innerText ("locators")-- giving null in the output

Tried with different locators and scripts but only displaying "" in the output, can someone help how to grab the value of last div

```html
<ul class="k-widget k-panelbar k-reset k-header" id="db4758565ab645a39013aadf65f30288" data-role="panelbar" tabindex="0" role="menu">
   <li class="k-item segment-confirmation-panel k-state-highlight k-state-active" role="menuitem" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-selected="true">
     <div class="k-content" id="db4758565ab645a39013aadf65f30288-2" role="region" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">    
       <div class="segment-details-panel-content">
         <div class="container selectable">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-2 noRightPadding bold">Supplier order id</div>
             <div class="col-xs-4 ">2380151</div>
```

Comment: ui automation is hard. you have to be creative and do some research: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845845/143475 - also try: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+locateAll and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+scriptAll